# Can I use Node.js on consoles?

Tags: xbox360, node.js, playstation3, playstation4

I was wondering if Node.js was suitable for making games and apart from threads and engines, a big problem is *can I port my game to Xbox or PS3/PS4?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Node.js runs on the V8 JavaScript engine](http://nodejs.org/):

> Node.js is a platform built on Chrome's JavaScript runtime for easily
>   building fast, scalable network applications. Node.js uses an
>   event-driven, non-blocking I/O model that makes it lightweight and
>   efficient, perfect for data-intensive real-time applications that run
>   across distributed devices.

[V8 itself is C++](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) and can be [embedded](https://developers.google.com/v8/embed) in any C++ application.

Thus, it is theoretically possible to use Node on consoles, although I'm not aware offhand of anybody who has tried. You may or may not run into porting issues as you would with any codebase.

That said, I don't see why you'd choose to use Node for client-side work on consoles, given the hoop-jumping you'll need to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you'll have a hard time using V8 on game consoles because it's going to need to generate code into writable executable pages, which usually isn't allowed.

If you ask the developer support folks for the console you're targeting, you may be able to make a business case to make this work.